# Enter network credentials (almost) every time I access a network share (NAS SMB)

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, samba

Windows 10 prompts me for password when I want to access a password-less network share. The share is on a NAS (SMB protocol). I can access the share from other OS/systems without any password just fine. I can type just anything on the prompt and it will accept.

Additional error displayed: *A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.*

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Disabling password protected sharing on Network and Sharing Center -> Advanced sharing settings -> All Networks -> Password protected sharing -> Turn off password protected sharing.
- Saving a credential on Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials -> Internet or network address = Share name.

Here's `smb.conf` from the NAS as requested:

```
[global]
dos charset = CP437
unix charset = UTF-8
display charset = UTF-8
netbios name = mynas
server string = "LinkStation"
socket options = TCP_NODELAY
max xmit = 65536
use sendfile = yes
os level = 1
wins server =

workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
auth methods = guest sam
passdb backend = tdbsam:/etc/samba/smbpasswd.tdb
encrypt passwords = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *New*password* %n\n *Retype*new*password* %n\n *passwd:*all*authentication*tokens*updated*successfully*
unix password sync = yes
unix extensions = no
guest account = nobody
null passwords = yes
guest only = no
password level = 14
map to guest = Bad User

veto files = /.AppleDesktop/Network Trash Folder/TheVolumeSettingsFolder/.AppleDouble/.AppleDB/.com.apple.timemachine.supported/
delete veto files = yes

deadtime = 15
invalid users = mail, deamon
admin users = root
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

log level = 1
max log size = 0

lock directory = /etc/samba/lock

dos filetimes = Yes
dos filetime resolution = No
map archive = Yes
map hidden = No
map system = No
dns proxy = No
show add printer wizard = No
host msdfs = no
disable spoolss = yes
wide links = yes
lanman auth = yes
printcap name = /etc/printcap
load printers =
```

And here's `smbusers`

```
# Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2 ...
root = administrator
nobody = guest pcguest smbguest
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133462/discussion-on-question-by-bortao-enter-network-credentials-almost-every-time-i).

Answer (score 5):

Since Windows 10 version 1709 and forward SMB2 and SMB3 disables guest access by default for it as a client connecting to an SMB server that forces guest or an unauthenticated credential.

Quoted and referenced below are portions of a Microsoft post that's relevant to your issue. I encourage you to read through its entire contents for thoroughness still.

I've also posted below some "potential solutions" for an answer even though for security reasons Microsoft says to not do this. You should ensure your network is locked down to prevent man-in-middle attacks for related systems.

> ### Symptoms
>
> Starting in Windows 10, version 1709 and Windows Server 2019, SMB2 and
> SMB3 clients no longer allow the following actions by default:
>
> - Guest account access to a remote server.
> - Fall back to the Guest account after invalid credentials are provided.
>
> SMB2 and SMB3 has the following behavior in these versions of Windows:
>
> - Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials by
>   default, even if the remote server requests guest credentials.
>
> **Note:**  This Windows 10 behavior occurs in Windows 10 1709, Windows 10 1803, Windows 10 1903, Windows 10 1909 as well as Windows 10 2004,
> Windows 10 20H2, & Windows 10 21H1 as long as
> [KB5003173](https://support.microsoft.com/topic/may-11-2021-kb5003173-os-builds-19041-985-19042-985-and-19043-985-2824ace2-eabe-4c3c-8a49-06e249f52527)
> is installed.
>
> If you try to connect to devices that request credentials of a guest
> instead of appropriate authenticated principals, you may receive error
> messages.
>
> Also, if a remote server tries to force you to use guest access, or if
> an administrator enables guest access, the following entries are
> logged in the SMB Client event log:
>
> ```
> Log Name: Microsoft-Windows-SmbClient/Security  
> Source: Microsoft-Windows-SMBClient  
> Date: Date/Time  
> Event ID: 31017  
> Task Category: None  
> Level: Error  
> Keywords: (128)  
> User: NETWORK SERVICE  
> Computer: ServerName.contoso.com  
> Description: Rejected an insecure guest logon.  
> User name: Ned  
> Server name: ServerName
> ```
>
> ### Guidance
>
> This event indicates that the server tried to log on the user as an
> unauthenticated guest but was denied by the client. Guest logons do
> not support standard security features such as signing and encryption.
> So, guest logons are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks that can
> expose sensitive data on the network. Windows disables insecure
> (nonsecure) guest logons by default. We recommend that you don't
> enable insecure guest logons.
>
> ### Cause
>
> This change in default behavior is by design and is recommended by
> Microsoft for security.
>
> [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default)

---

## Potential Solutions

**Note:** Restart the system if you make any of these changes and then try again after the reboot. Sometimes to become effective in Windows, a reboot is required after making a registry or Group Policy change.

**First**, use this PowerShell to enable, disable, or remove the [AllowInsecureGuestAuth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-workstationservice-allowinsecureguestauth)

```
$x = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters" -Name "AllowInsecureGuestAuth";
If ($x) {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters" -Name "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" -Value 1 -Force;
    } Else {
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters" -Name "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" -PropertyType "DWORD" -Value 1 -Force;
    }
```

**Note:** You can undo this by changing the `-Value 1` code to `-Value 0`

---

**Second**, you can try to uninstall the [KB5003173](https://support.microsoft.com/topic/may-11-2021-kb5003173-os-builds-19041-985-19042-985-and-19043-985-2824ace2-eabe-4c3c-8a49-06e249f52527) as per the post that says this is the update that makes this security change effective.

---

**Third**, you could try to set the local or domain Group Policy to enable insecure guest access with settings:

1. Open the **Local Group Policy Edito**r (gpedit.msc).
2. In the console tree, select Computer **Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Lanman Workstation**.
3. For the setting, right-click **Enable insecure guest logons** and select **Edit**.
4. Select **Enabled** and select **OK**.

---

**Fourth**, following applicable steps on the [How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3) post you could try to enabled SMBv1. Or you could enable SMBv1 and then disable SMBv2, and SMBv3 to see if that forces the SMBv1 to be used that doesn't have the security constraint.

---

**Fifth**, an additional thing to try while having the registry options set per the above steps, and after a reboot once that is set, would to run a command line or two but NOT elevated as admin.

1. Delete all existing mappings (in case of conflicts)

> ```
> net use * /delete
> ```

2. Next run one of these variations but `/user:guest` may need to be `/user:<remoteMachineIPAddress>\guest`

> ```
> net use \\serverName\shareName "" /user:guest /persistent:yes 
> net use \\serverName\shareName /user:guest "" /persistent:yes
> ```

Using one of those two formats above while considering the note regarding `/user:XX.XX.XX.XX\guest` making that match  the actual IP of the remote SMB/NAS system, this might allow subsequent connections without needing to retype the credential each time.

You should test with a reboot to see if this solution sticks after a reboot. Consider adding it as a login script or dropping applicable logic to the `/startup` folder in Windows so it runs at each (or the needed) user login if after a reboot it needs rerun again.

### Batch Script

**Note:** *Drop a copy into to the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` directory.*

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT DEFINED MINIMIZED SET MINIMIZED=1 && START "" /MIN "%~F0" x && EXIT
net use \\serverName\shareName /user:guest "" /persistent:yes
EXIT
```

Comment: So I did all this but still get the login prompt. Guest access is enabled, I can login with guest/empty password, but this login isn't done automatically.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it doesn't persist after reboot. If I issue the command it connect to the share, so I could add this to a startup script, even though it's not an ideal solution it may be the only one.

Comment: @bortao Hi, seems like we're getting closer to at least get a feasible working solution for you even if it is kind of brute force. I went ahead and added the applicable comment notes I provided to the end of my answer for completeness sake. I also provided an example batch script with the startup folder method and put some logic that should fully minimize the cmd window when it runs if that's the route you have to take. If you need to put as a login script, do so as a login script and not a startup script though. I assume you're already familiar with where to define but I'm happy to help more.

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails, try adding a user password to your windows login.  That is what it took for me to access without needing credentials.  I had originally left my password blank.  once I added a password and then I used a PIN I was able to get into my NAS shares without issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).